# My scrollView does appear but does not work

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

I'm working on a wpf project and I wanna have a `scrollViewer` scrolling a `DataGrid` that I fill dynamically
No matter how many rows I have in my DataGrid, I'm always able to see my scrollview but I'm not able to scroll with it

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="6" Padding="11"
                 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                          Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                 >
                <DataGrid
                Grid.Row="6"
                Margin="10 10 10 10"
                x:Name="DataInformation"
                Grid.ColumnSpan="4">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="country" Width="*" Header="Country" Binding="{Binding Path=countryRegion}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="province" Width="*" Header="Region / State" Binding="{Binding Path=provinceState}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lastU" Width="*" Header="lastUpdate" Binding="{Binding Path=lastUpdate}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lat" Width="*" Header="lat" Binding="{Binding Path=lat}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="lon" Width="*" Header="lon" Binding="{Binding Path=lon}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="confirmed" Width="*" Header="confirmed" Binding="{Binding Path=confirmed}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="recovered" Width="*" Header="recovered" Binding="{Binding Path=recovered}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="death" Width="*" Header="death" Binding="{Binding Path=deaths}" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn x:Name="active" Width="*" Header="active" Binding="{Binding Path=active}" />
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
```

Thanks a lot !

Comment: Please copy-paste your code here so we can observe it. Also, why you even need to place a `DataGrid` to `ScrollViewer`? If your grid does not fit into the area you placed it to, you'll get the scrolling anyway.

Comment: A DataGrid alreday has its own scroller, why do you wrap this in a separate scroll view? I suppose both scroll views (integrated and yours) prevent each other from working.

Comment: @AntonPapin, thx I haded the code (a bit reduced because it was quit long) to the question. When I'm filling the grid with data, it does not fit but without the add of my "ScrollView" I don't even have a Scroll bar on the screen, and when I had it, it is on screen but not working

Answer (score 1):

The main reason why scrolling isn't working is because you have your controls placed in a `StackPanel`. `StackPanel`s layout mechanism prevents scrolling.

I recommend that you:

1. Remove the `StackPanel`
2. Remove the extra `ScrollViewer` you added

The `DataGrid` should allow scrolling within the `Grid`.

I hope this helps.